# Add comments in pdf

Tags: pdf, comments, latex

I want to add some text in a pdf document from latex. The text is not supposed to be seen in the  actual PDF, I want it more to be like a comment in a code, so I can load the "code" in a program and read the comments. Is this possible?

Kind regards

Comment: You seem to be looking for [File Attachments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#File_attachments) in pdf.

Comment: If you want to use LaTeX to carry out the task, you should ask your question at [tex.se].

Comment: LaTeX does allow for attaching documents to PDF output. See the [`attachfile2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) and [`embedfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) packages.

Comment: What about `cooltooltips` package?

Example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes/9804#9804

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Latex enough to comment on that part of your question, but there are a number of different ways information can be stored inside PDF files that would satisfy your question.

Images in PDF files are typically objects (Image XObjects to be exact) - these have a dictionary where additional information could be stored next to the image data.

PDF supports the concept of object metadata where XMP metadata can be embedded in a PDF file for a specific object. This would be a second way to embed additional non-visible information in the PDF file (and a better one).

And perhaps best of all if you can generate this from Latex is the fact that PDF allows object properties, which uses marked content operators in the page stream to delineate a number of objects and then allows associating information to that marked content.

All of those should be easy to find in the PDF specification on the Adobe website; what would remain would be to figure out what ways you have in Latex to generate any of this and what you'd have to do to read them in your program :-)

Answer (score -2):

There are two different ways:

You can either comment out single lines by adding a % in front of them

```
% This text will be a comment
```

Or you can comment out larger sections by doing this:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{comment}
This text will be commented out.
\end{comment}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want a comment in my latex document. I want to have it in the actual PDF.

Comment: These are latex comments. The OP wants inserting comments inside PDF using latex.

Comment: "The text is not supposed to be seen in the actual PDF".. ??